# Синтаксис heredoc и CSS

Tags: php, css

Как в конструкцию

```
print <<<HERE

HERE;
```

Вставить CSS

```
<style type="text/css"> 
#header 
{
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-left: 750px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Это скорее не heredoc не работает а сами стили... посмотрите в исходном коде страницы в браузере...если ваши стили там есть, то все в поряде в выдаче... ищите в другом месте траблу

Comment: @Ёхарный Бабай Все стили изначально работают, но мне необходимо эту часть поместить в heredoc

Comment: Так Вы посмотрите в исходном коде, в браузер именно эта часть кода загружается??? Если загружается, то heredoc тут непричем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте конструкцию:

```
<?php

            ob_start();
        include 'while.php';
        $include = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        print <<<HERE

        {$include}

        HERE;

        ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Взять и вставить :-)

```
print <<<HERE

<style type="text/css"> 
#header

{

  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-left: 750px;

}
</style>

HERE;
```

В чём проблема то?

Comment: @mantigatos Уже пробовал и результат 0